# Using reflection to set a non-static field

Tags: java, minecraft

```
    public static void setMOTD(final String motd) throws Exception {
    final Field field = MinecraftServer.class.getDeclaredField("motd");
    final Field server = CraftServer.class.getDeclaredField("console");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    server.setAccessible(true);
    MinecraftServer instance = (MinecraftServer) server.get(CraftServer.class);
    field.set(instance, motd);
}
```

My goal with this is to change the Message of the day on a minecraft server (running craftbukkit). To do this I need to change a non-static field motd. I am doing all of this with a plugin so I can't get the instance for the MinecraftServer. The second last line was my attempt at doing this with reflection however it failed. I don't have access to change the MinecraftServer class or CraftServer because they are in an external library.

motd and console are both non-static fields.

motd is a String with the modifiers public final.

console is an instance of MinecraftServer with the modifiers protected final.

This is the error I'm getting (on the second last line of setMOTD):

```
2012-07-22 22:16:31 [SEVERE] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set final net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer field org.bukkit.craftbukkit.CraftServer.console to java.lang.Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by fetching the bukkit instance which extends CraftServer

```
    public static void setServerMOTD(final String motd) throws Exception {
    final Field field = MinecraftServer.class.getDeclaredField("motd");
    final Field server = CraftServer.class.getDeclaredField("console");
    Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
    modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
    field.setAccessible(true);
    server.setAccessible(true);
    modifiersField.setInt(server, server.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
    MinecraftServer instance = (MinecraftServer) server.get(Bukkit.getServer());
    field.set(instance, motd);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

re-reading the error message, it seems to be at odds with your code.  the error message seems to imply that you are trying to *set* the `console` member variable to an invalid object type.  please confirm the code you are actually testing.

Comment: Would something like this work?
  Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");

     modifiersField.setAccessible(true);

     modifiersField.setInt(server, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

I still seem to be getting the same error though (without the final modifier in the exception).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the field console is marked 'final' in the CraftServer class, based on the error message.

This means once set you will not be able to change it which would happen before reflection gets a chance to modify it.

You may not be able to change this behaviour if CraftServer is part of the library

Comment: That seems to be my problem, I'm trying to find a way around this but nothing seems to work. I will submit a pull on github to craftbukkit for the future, however I am looking for a temporary solution with reflection. (first time using reflection)

Comment: yeah, not much you can do to override this behaviour most of the time it is designed this way to prevent programmers for using libraries in undesireable ways.  There must be another way to do what you're planning

Comment: There is in a newer version, however I want to support the majority of servers which are running on an older version of craftbukkit which doesn't yet support this. Also thanks for the quick replies :)

Comment: Hmm, double check to see that its not a configuration item that is set in a property somewhere, seems like the kind of thing that would be ideally set that way if it is

Comment: It is a property however I want to change it during runtime for my plugin as seen in this issue: https://github.com/Monstercraft/MonsterIRC/issues/229

Comment: I like his last few words: and probably fairly easy to implement.

Comment: The error message doesn't say anything about not being to set a final field via Reflection. The problem lies elsewhere, as the error message shows. He is doing a get(), not a set(, when the exception is thrown. Not an answer.